# How to use ServiceStack to get denormalized array of objects

Tags: sql, sql-server, orm, servicestack

Could someone please provide or link to a simple-as-can-be example of how to use ServiceStack to return a denormalized array of objects from an existing SQLServer database with several joins?

The returned objects would only have a small subset of the columns from the query, and will have different names.

I would have preferred to use ORMLite, but am happy to use EF if need be.  I will be using this for read only operations.

E.g. if I was to query a db with the following joined tables: `Customer`, `Order`, `Orderline`, I would like to return a De-normalized list, like the following, but using different column names than used on the db:

- Customer Name
- Order Date
- OrderLine Number
- Prod Desc
- Qty

Comment: Have switched over to use Dapper - and with the help of @Damith, got it sorted [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950919/dapper-returning-a-sub-set-of-specific-columns-directly-into-dto).  SS & Dapper make a great combo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/) you can always fallback to custom SQL if you ever need to do a complex query or custom joins, e.g:

```
List<CustomerProductOrder> results = db.Select<CustomerProductOrder>(
  @"SELECT c.Name, o.Date, ol.Number, p.Desc, o.Qty
      FROM Order o INNER JOIN Customer c ON (o.CustomerId = c.Id) ...
     WHERE o.Id = {0}", 1001);
```

Or alternatively by using a parameterized query, e.g:

```
List<CustomerProductOrder> results = db.Query<CustomerProductOrder>(
  @"SELECT c.Name, o.Date, ol.Number, p.Desc, o.Qty
      FROM Order o INNER JOIN Customer c ON (o.CustomerId = c.Id)  ...
     WHERE o.Id = @orderId", new { orderId = 1001 });
```

Where `CustomerProductOrder` is a denormalized POCO for this query which will populate all the properties with the matching columns from the result set.

More OrmLite querying examples can be found on [OrmLite's API Overview](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/#api-overview).

Comment: Thanks mythz.  What arguments does the .Select method take.  The docs conflict with the error message I'm getting: "Using the generic method 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Select<TRow,S>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection<TRow>, System.Func<TRow,S>)' requires 2 type arguments"

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks @mythz, just what I was after. Identical to [Dapper](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950919/dapper-returning-a-sub-set-of-specific-columns-directly-into-dto).